# Why kubectl returns pods with 'Terminating' status when I query for just running pods?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, k3s

[image]

I have a [k3s](https://k3s.io/) cluster with some pods running. I want to get all pods with status of *Running* containing *grafana* in its name.

From the docs, looks like I can use [field selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/) flag to achieve it ([was introduced in v1.9 release](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/50140?w=1)). But when I give it a try, it didn't work.

I know I can force delete the pod with *Terminating* status to get what I want. What I want to know here is, why my command didn't work as expected? Did i miss something?

Btw, the *Terminating* pod was there for some time. I believe it's stuck. But again, that's not the interest of this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look into [k8s documentation on pod-lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase) you can see that status.phase can have only 5 different values and none of them is  `Terminating`. This means that termination state in not reflected in this field and therefore filtering by the phase field is useless.

Terminating status is reflected under `.status.containerStatuses.state` ([container states in docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-states)) although this field label doesn't seem to be supported by the filter.

---

So what can you do?

The easiest thing you can do is to use grep twice:

```
kubectl get pods | grep grafana | grep Running
```